# Search javascript object for any value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects. I'd like to run a global search accross all values within each object and return that object.

Data

```
const data = [
  {
    firstName: 'Brady',
    lastName: 'Smith'
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Jason',
    lastName: 'Brady'
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Michael',
    lastName: 'Bolten'
  }
];
```

How do I search for Brady across all values to return both Brady Smith and Jason Brady objects? If there is an es6 way that would be great.

Current attempt

```
const filteredData = data
  .map(item => {
    if (Object.values(item) === 'Brady') {
      return item;
    }
  })
  .filter(function(element) {
    return element != null;
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `filter` and `find`

```js
const data = [{firstName: 'Brady',lastName: 'Smith'},{firstName: 'Jason',lastName: 'Brady'},{firstName: 'Michael',lastName: 'Bolten'}];

const filteredData = data.filter(data=>
     Object.values(data).some(val=> val === 'Brady')
)
  
console.log(filteredData)
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to `map` the array.

You can use `filter` and `includes` to check if a string is on the array.

```js
const data = [{
    firstName: 'Brady',
    lastName: 'Smith'
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Jason',
    lastName: 'Brady'
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Michael',
    lastName: 'Bolten'
  }
];

const filteredData = data.filter(o => Object.values(o).includes('Brady'));

console.log(filteredData);
```